# Model Method Not Working in Another's View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on an application that involves "follow/unfollow" functionality. `Users` can follow `Objects` and `Objects` can have many `Users` following them. It's a `has_many :through` relationship via a `Relationships` model/controller.

I have the following snippet in the `object#show` view:

```
<% if current_user.following?(@object) %>
  <%= render 'unfollow' %>
<% else %>
  <%= render 'follow' %>
<% end %>
```

When testing various functionalities in a request spec, it shows `undefined method 'following?' for nil:NilClass` and fails all of the `object#show` specs.

The `following?` method is in the `User` model and looks like this:

```
def following?(object)
  relationships.find_by_object_id(object.id)
end
```

The method `following?` is in the `User` model (since they are the only ones doing following and unfollowing). I thought you could use methods between objects in Ruby, but perhaps not. If not, how would I go about refactoring this to be able to use that method?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: It's a public method too in the User model, not a private method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `current_user` helper in specs. That's why you get `nil`.
You should stab test user into `current_user` variable

Comment: I'm not referencing `current_user` at all in the spec itself, just in the object's actual view. I create a user in the specs using FactoryGirl and use that as the current_user (after logging it in).

Comment: Try to ensure what user truly logged in

Comment: Thanks- I rechecked and found one method that wasn't included in the limiter for only logged in users! Thanks for the help!